# When does there an analytic function $f:F\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ has an analytic logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Is the following assertion true?

Let $f:F\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function, is it true that $\log f(z)$ has an analytic branch if and only if $f$ is zero free and $f(F)$, the image of $F$ under $f$ does not have a hole containing the origin?

I think this will be the case since the the logarithm is analytic in a domain $F$, if and only if $F$ does not contain zero and $F$ does not have a hole containing zero (so that we can always choose the branch cut to stay away from $F$).

I guess I am also using the following claim which seems to be true. Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic functions, then $f(g(z))$ is analytic on a set $F$ if and only if $g(z)$ is analytic on $F$ and $f(z)$ is analytic on $f(F)$.

Are my claims correct? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: no that is not correct - for example if $F$ is simply connected, any analytic $f$ that doesn't vanish on $F$ has an analytic logarithm because you can fix a base point $w$ (and a fixed value of  $\log f(w)$ from its infinitely many possibilities - eg the principal branch if $f(w)$ is not a negative real, $\log |f(w)|+i \pi$ if it is) ) and get analytic logarithms by continuation on curves; simply connectedness implies that on a closed curve you return to the branch you started so the continuations patch well

Comment: We have to split hairs: By "$\log f(z)$ has an analytic branch on $F$" do you mean, 1. "There exists an analytic $g$ on $F$ such that $f = \exp(g)$" (as in Robert's answer), or 2. "There exists an analytic branch of $\log$ on the image $f(F)$"? <> Those are not the same question, and the answers differ.

Comment: Linking your [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794062/a-counter-example-that-i-cannot-find-an-analytic-branch-of-logarithm) in the hope of forestalling duplicated effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you mean by "a hole".  But you might consider the case of $f(z) = \exp(z)$ with, say, $F = \mathbb C$, where $f(F)$ is the complex plane with $0$ removed, and yet $\log(f(z))$ has an analytic branch, namely $z$.